# ezSQL-like SQL library for ASP classic?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Is there a SQL library handling simple sql related tasks for ASP classic? What I have in mind is sql to array, multiple insert, input sanitizing etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very much NOT an asp guy.... but the ADODB recordset object is what we use at work.  "input sanitizing" is like alchemy.... you can never quite get all the way there.  Always use parametrized queries/stored procedures.

Some quick little example snippets are here...

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=9428

Comment: Thank you for answering; still, I am looking for a library that would minimize redundancy and provide input sanitizing. Cheers --Andre

Comment: Using parametrized queries will sanitize your input by limiting the length of chars submitted to those held in the SP or db table, as well as the data type.  Also, the need for sanitizing for things like apostrophe's ('), comment marks (--) and other stuff you never thought of is unnecessary.  The program will not interpret ANY data passed in by the user as syntax.  It will only use it as part of the intended parameter.

Comment: oh, and finally, to solve the repetitive nature of using those types of objects, at my company we've automated the creation of a data access layer that reads the properties of a stored procedure (type & # of arguments) and creates the code.  The manually prepared code need only call a function of a known name (which is denoted in a ReferenceData table that is used by the code automation program (in this case, that program is "codesmith")